# WSO2 APIM 2.0 Gateway-Worker-Node: "the requested resource XXX is not available"

Tags: api, synchronization, wso2, wso2-api-manager, worker

I have a gatewaymanager (GWM) with 2 worker nodes. When I deploy an API its pushed to the GWM and is available threre --> API-Call works fine.

I decided to synchronize the APIs from the GWM to the worker nodes via rsync. The filesystems under ~wso2/repository/deployment/server on the workernodes are synced and similar to the GWM node.
But when I call the API on a worker node I get this message:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>404</am:code>
<am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Not Found</am:message>
<am:description>The requested resource (/XXX/1/foo) is not available.
</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

I also restarted the workes, but same result.

Did I miss something or is there a trigger to load the APIs on the workers to the cache, or something like this?

Comment: It looks like APIs are not synced with gw worker nodes. Do you see the API in the synapse location (wso2am-home/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/ ) ? Make sure rsync is working properly.

Comment: Yes. The folders are synced and the the API files are at the worker nodes.

Comment: You can also check the gw cluster is working fine. Do you see 'Member joined' log at the startup of the gw servers? You should see this log in 2 of the gw nodes.

Comment: I lied to you. The API wasnt sync to wso2am-home/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/de‌​fault/api/ but wso2am-home/repository/deployment/server/server/synapse-configs/de‌​fault/api/.
A bug in my sync script. Thank you for your help. The API is reachable via the workers now.

Comment: Glad to hear it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue , when the contents of mediation files were changed.
**Solution which worked for me **

1. Demote your api to created
2. Ensure gateway is checked
3. Redeploy it